# MongoDB for small datasets

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mongodb, nosql

Are there any benefits to using MongoDB for a Node.js application rather than a traditional SQL database such as MySQL, if I'm not planning to have large (>1000 item) collections and am already comfortable with SQL?

Comment: not really, none I can think of

Comment: @Sammaye are you kidding? the entire data model is completely different and is so much closer to what the data structures already look like in a node.js application - what does it matter how much data there is?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky And a different data structure would make a noticeable difference outside of developing the application? Like in terms of performance etc? I think he is looking for benefits really and if he is comfortable with SQL he will have an ORM or something which forms SQL flat structures into node.js structures making very little difference application side between MongoDB and SQL. This means the different data structure is not as much of a benefit as it might seem since SQL, with some fancy programming, can act the same and the developer would never know.

Comment: This is a Q&A site for developers. Speed and simplicity of development somehow seems relevant to me.

Comment: I'm looking for any benefits that would justify selection of MongoDB in this architecture, this would include speed of development and ease of deployment. However, Node.js includes addons for querying both MySQL and MongoDB, I assume both addons return data in a similar format and the main difference would be the language used to query the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB is schema-less document based database. This means you can insert a JSON object with other nested objects. This can make development easier, especially for prototyping.

For a small project, why not? For a larger project you should do more research. Large or small, doesn't hurt to do the research anyway. You want to consider how your application uses the database (reads vs writes) and how MongoDB scales horizontally, and how it handles failures.

There's a thing called the CAP theorem that defines NoSQL databases. MongoDB is CP. This [visual guide](http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems) shows the relationships between different databases. What is most important to you and your application?

Something else to consider is that most NoSQL databases are not ACID compliant. If you're using MySQL with InnoDB, that can be something significant to give up, depending on your application. For example, [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) might be something you might not want to give up.

Lots of pros and cons. Best thing to ask yourself is: What am I gaining? What am I giving up? There are many things, and it really depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons to stick with a simple dbms for a small-scale application. One of them is the widespread availability of cheap hosting services providing MySQL. Another is ease of deployment and maintenance.

Of course, if you're trying to learn to use MongoDB, go for it!

Comment: I dunno about the maintanence part etc, I have used both and actually once you got the basic grasps MongoDB is easier to develop for and about as easy to admin really, the main point is the hosting probably.